# java regexp for nested parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

Consider the following java String:

```
String input = "a, b, (c, d), e, f, (g, (h, i))";
```

Can you help me to find a java regexp to obtain its 6 parts:

```
a
b
(c,d)
e
f
(g, (h,i))
```

That were obtained from the original  input string based in the "most external" commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to use regex for this kind of task in Java since here regex doesn't support recursion and you could end up with monster regex like shown in [Is it possible to match nested brackets with a regex without using recursion or balancing groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162098/is-it-possible-to-match-nested-brackets-with-a-regex-without-using-recursion-or).

Simplest solution would be writing your own parser which would count balance of `(` and `)` (lets call it nesting level) and will split only on `,` if nesting level would be `0`.

Code for this task (which will also solve this problem in **one iteration**) could look like

```
public static List<String> splitOnNotNestedCommas(String data){
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList();
    
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int nestingLvl = 0;
    for (char ch : data.toCharArray()){
        if (ch == '(') nestingLvl++;
        if (ch == ')') nestingLvl--;
        if (ch == ',' & nestingLvl==0){
            resultList.add(sb.toString().trim());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());
        }else{
            sb.append(ch);
        }
    }
    if (sb.length()>0)
        resultList.add(sb.toString().trim());
    
    return resultList;
}
```

Usage:

```
for (String s : splitOnNotNestedCommas("a, b, (c, d), e, f, (g, (h, i))")){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
(c, d)
e
f
(g, (h, i))
```