# Conditional usage of "(" and ")"

Tags: java, regex, format

what is the regex format for the usage of ')' if and only if '(' is used earlier, or ')' is must if '(' is used? I have tried `^[a-zA-Z]+(([)]?[,]?[a-zA-Z0-9 ][. -/']?[(]?[a-zA-Z0-9][)]?)?[a-zA-Z:.])$` . But I can't make it use ')' only when '(' is being used.

Comment: you need to be more specific, what do you mean "use" ')' only when '(' is being used? Do you mean entering a sentence? or cleaning an input?

Comment: I want to make sure that they are used in pair.

Comment: what do you mean used? what is the context of your program, give us some information man

Comment: possible duplicate of [java regexp for nested parenthesis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26329339/java-regexp-for-nested-parenthesis)

Answer (score 3):

Regex cannot take care of context. In your case you're seeking to find context. Regex is not meant for that. You need to write a function that checks this.

Citing from [this link](https://nikic.github.io/2012/06/15/The-true-power-of-regular-expressions.html):

> In the context of formal language theory, something is called
>   “regular” when it has a grammar where all production rules have one of
>   the following forms:
>
> 1. B -> a
> 2. B -> aC
> 3. B -> ε
>
> You can read those -> rules as “The left hand side can be replaced
>   with the right hand side”. So the first rule would be “B can be
>   replaced with a”, the second one “B can be replaced with aC” and the
>   third one “B can be replaced with the empty string” (ε is the symbol
>   for the empty string).
>
> So what are B, C and a? By convention, uppercase characters denote so
>   called “non-terminals” - symbols which can be broken down further -
>   and lowercase characters denote “terminals” - symbols which cannot be
>   broken down any further.

In your case you are looking for something like:

```
(\([x].*\)[x])*
```

I added the `[x]` to stand for an `x` number of times (it's not part of the regex convention of course). As you can see by the definition of regex, there's no way to represent such expression in a way that complies with regex definition.

This is not just a "grey" definition issue. Creating a regex-like language to solve problems like the one you noted here is much more complicated (algorithmic and complexity wise). It's a totally different problem domain to try and patternize the type of problems as the one you mentioned here.