# Extractor object and class in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm writing extractor object for functions expressions. Here is how it looks like:

```
object FunctionTemplate2 {
  private final val pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)\\((.+?)\\,(.+?)\\)")
  //e.g. foo(1, "str_arg")
  def unapply(functionCallExpression: String): Option[(String, String, String)] = {
      //parse expression and extract
  }
}
```

And I can extract as follows:

```
"foo(1, \"str_arg\")" match {
  case FunctionTemplate2("foo", first, second) =>
    println(s"$first,$second")
}
```

But this is not as cute as it could be. I would like to have something like that:

```
case FunctionTemplate2("foo")(first, second) =>
  println(s"$first,$second")
```

Like curried extractor. So I tried this:

```
case class Function2Extractor(fooName: String){
  private final val pattern = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)\\((.+?)\\,(.+?)\\)")
  println("creating")
  def unapply(functionCallExpression: String): Option[(String, String, String)] = 
    //parse and extract as before
}
```

But it did not work:

```
"foo(1, \"str_arg\")" match {
  case Function2Extractor("foo")(first, second) =>
    println(s"$first,$second")
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Scala?

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to prettify the irrelevant parts right now. A much more severe problem would be that your current approach does not scale beyond anything but non-nested functions with string arguments that don't contain commas, like `foo("bar", "baz")` but not `foo(bar("baz","cov"),"fefe")` or `foo("bar, baz", "bus")`. You could of course attempt to [parse nested parentheses with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162098), but I doubt that it will be easier than using a proper parser.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin As I can see it can scale to nested functions. If we parse it recursively and build parse tree.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply it by using some utilities in Scala toolset

Notice how `pattern` is used in match case.

## Scala REPL

```
scala> val pattern = "^(.+?)\\((.+?)\\,(.+?)\\)".r
pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^(.+?)\((.+?)\,(.+?)\)

scala> "foo(1, \"str_arg\")" match  { case pattern(x, y, z) => println(s"$x $y $z")}
foo 1  "str_arg"
```

Comment: Don't understand how it can help. We still have the same `pattern(x, y, z)`, but not `pattern(x)(y, z)`. Can you expand?

Comment: `pattern(x)(y, z)` cannot be done and it is because of how unapply works in Scala

Comment: Why can't we make `pattern(x)` to be something like `case class pattern(x){ def unapply(y, z) = //...}`. So we have extractor method...

Comment: Pattern matching works by tuple comparison. `pattern(x)(y, z)` is percieved as passing x as parameters while case matching. clearly will be compilation error