# what is the match for this regex \g{2}(a)(b)

Tags: regex, backreference

I am learning regex and i have a case related to backreference.

- e.g. with `(a)(b)\g{2}` will match the result `abb`
- however for the case `\g{2}(a)(b)` I haven't found a match yet.
- I don't know why either. Can anyone explain to me how this backreference works. thank you very much. Sorry for my bad English

I tried replacing index 2 with 3 or less than 1, but it gives regex syntax error. It can be understood that here only two indexes are allowed, 1 and 2, corresponding to the positions of the 2 existing groups. however with `\g{2}(a)(b)` the results like `bab` or `aab` or `ab` do not match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786985/backref-before-associated-group)

Comment: Oh thank you. I have read the article and learned new knowledge