# Recursive Regex in SPARQL query to identify matching parentheses

Tags: regex, sparql, jena

I'm trying to use SPARQL to query literals that have regexes with balanced parentheses.
So "( (1) ((2)) (((3))) 4)" should be returned, but "( (1) ((2)) (((3)) 4)", where I removed a closing parenthesis after the "3", should not be returned.

I've previously looked here for a suitable regex: [Regular expression to match balanced parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-balanced-parentheses)

And have been trying to implement regex suggested by rogal111, which is as follows:

```
\(([^()]|(?R))*\)
```

This regex follows the PCRE syntax, which I understand is the W3C standard and should be followed by SPARQL.
According to the linked example http://regex101.com/r/lF0fI1/1 this should work for the examples above.

I've tested this on both a Jena based triple store, and a Virtuoso based triple store.

**Jena**: when I try to implement it for SPARQL with the query below, it says that the (?R) inline modifier is unknown.

```
SELECT ?lf
WHERE
{
  BIND("(test)" AS ?l)
  FILTER REGEX(?l, "\\(([^()]|(?R))*\\)").
}
```

The complete error message that is returned is below.

```
Regex pattern exception: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 11 \(([^()]|(?R))*\)
```

**Virtuoso**: The Virtuoso based triple store (tested on: https://sparql.uniprot.org/sparql) does work, but also returns incorrect outputs, as exemplified with the query below:

```
SELECT ?lf
WHERE
{
  BIND("((test)" AS ?l)
  FILTER REGEX(?l, "\\(([^()]|(?R))*\\)").
}
```

I'm not sure whether this is intentional, a bug, or that I'm doing something wrong. Ultimately I want to get it to work on the Jena based triplestore. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: most of the RDF tools (including Jena) are written in Java but Java regex libraray does not support regex recursion. look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162098 where a non-recursive solution is discussed and apply it to your case. Also suggest to use `REPLACE` instead of `REGEX` and apply a filter to check if the result of the replacement is empty which indicates that whole literal matches

Comment: Java regex does not support recursion.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses! So if I understand your answers correctly, Java based triple stores cannot fully implement the https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/ recommendation?
I'll look at an alternative solution then.

Comment: @Wytz SPARQL grammar REGEXP at https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex points to XPath and XQuery section at https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax which in turn lead to https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#regexs and nowhere in these documents I could find a reference that it require support of recursion ...

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov You are correct, it appears that I misinterpreted the description on https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax. I thought it meant that even though the syntax may sometimes differ from e.g. Perl (which they refer to, and which should be PCRE I believe), it would broadly offer the same validity checking functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify and augment my comment about the use of `REPLACE`, the following should work:

```
SELECT * 
{
    VALUES ?value { 
        "( (1) ((2)) (((3))) 4)" 
        "( (1) ((2)) (((3)) 4)"
        "before (test) after" 
        "before ((test) after"
    }
    bind(!regex(
            replace(?value, '(?=\\()(?:(?=.*?\\((?!.*?\\1)(.*\\)(?!.*\\2).*))(?=.*?\\)(?!.*?\\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\\1)[^(]*(?=\\2$)', '') 
            , '[()]') as ?result)
}
```