# Regex: starts with messages and string between parent message curly brace

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to get all the message data. Such that it should look for message and all the data between curly braces of the parent message. With the below pattern, I am not getting all parent body.

```
 String data = "syntax = \"proto3\";\r\n" + 
            "package grpc;\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "import \"envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate/validate/validate.proto\";\r\n" + 
            "import \"google/api/annotations.proto\";\r\n" + 
            "import \"google/protobuf/wrappers.proto\";\r\n" + 
            "import \"protoc-gen-swagger/options/annotations.proto\";\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "message Acc {\r\n" + 
            "    message AccErr {\r\n" + 
            "        enum Enum {\r\n" + 
            "            UNKNOWN = 0;\r\n" + 
            "            CASH = 1;\r\n" + 
            "        }\r\n" + 
            "    }\r\n" + 
            "    string account_id = 1;\r\n" + 
            "    string name = 3;\r\n" + 
            "    string account_type = 4;\r\n" + 
            "}\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "message Name {\r\n" + 
            "    string firstname = 1;\r\n" + 
            "    string lastname = 2;\r\n" + 
            "}";
        List<String> allMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("message[^\\}]*\\}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String str = matcher.group();
            allMessages.add(str);
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
```

I am expecting response like below in my array list of string with size 2.

`allMessage.get(0)` should be:

```
message Acc {
    message AccErr {
        enum Enum {
            UNKNOWN = 0;
            CASH = 1;
        }
    }
    string account_id = 1;
    string name = 3;
    string account_type = 4;
}
```

and `allMessage.get(1)` should be:

```
message Name {
    string firstname = 1;
    string lastname = 2;
}
```

Comment: I guess that will do.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162098/is-it-possible-to-match-nested-brackets-with-a-regex-without-using-recursion-or

Comment: Your problem is that you are hitting `}` tokens before the one you are seeking, such as the one that closes the `enum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the input prior to `"message"` appearing at the start of the line, then split on newlines followed by `"message"` (include the newlines in the split so newlines that intervene parent messages are consumed):

```
String[] messages = data.replaceAll("(?sm)\\A.*?(?=message)", "").split("\\R+(?=message)");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/FaT6LW).

If you actually need a `List<String>`, pass that result to `Arrays.asList()`:

```
List<String> = Arrays.asList(data.replaceAll("(?sm)\\A.*?(?=message)", "").split("\\R+(?=message)"));
```

The first regex matches everything from start up to, but not including, the first line that starts with message, which is replaced with a blank (ie deleted). Breaking the down:

- `(?sm)` turns on flags `s`, which makes dot also match newlines, and `m`, which makes `^` and `$` match start and end of each line
- `\\A` means the very start of input
- `.*?` `.*` means any quantity of any character (including newline as per the `s` flag being set), but adding `?` makes this *reluctant*, so it matches as *few* characters as possible while still matching
- `(?=^message)` is a *look ahead* and means the following characters are a start of a line then `"message"`

See [regex101 live demo](https://regex101.com/r/i8VNzf/1) for a thorough explanation.

The split regex matches one or more line break sequences when they are followed by `"message"`:

- `\\R+` means one or more line break sequences (all OS variants)
- `(?=message)` is a *look ahead* and means the following characters are `"message"`

See [regex101 live demo](https://regex101.com/r/ztSykl/1) for a thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks with the above approach I am getting all data in in single list of string. I want to split based on messages. So, with the above example I should get array list of size two. Editing the question.

Comment: @Maana This code produces *two* strings. Please copy paste my code into your IDE and try. You can see it produces 2 strings in the linked live demo. (I made some edits since the original posting, so you may not be using the latest version of my answer)

Comment: Bohemian: Can you please explain that pattern meaning if you don't mind or any reference link.

Comment: @Maana Explanations added

Comment: If my string contain any extra things like service below which I don't want to included in my list how to do that any suggestion ? 
service Service { 
    rpc getBalance() returns (response) {
 }
}

Comment: @Maana ask another question! (And tell me its link - there is another approach entirely that will work for more complicated situations, but it deserves its own question)

Comment: created new question please advice thanks- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71021550/regex-only-returns-message-string-thats-starts-with-messages-and-string-betw

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your regex.  It anchors on `message` being the start of a line, and uses a positive lookahead to find the next message or the end of messages.

```java
Pattern.compile("(?s)\r\n(message.*?)(?=(\r\n)+message|$)")
// or
Pattern.compile("(?s)\r?\n(message.*?)(?=(\r?\n)+message|$)")
```

No spliting, parsing, or managing nested braces either :)

https://regex101.com/r/Wa2xxx/1

Comment: But a lot more lines of code in the complete solution.

Comment: Joining the matched groups is 'a lot more lines of code?'

Comment: Just saying the full working code that uses a `Pattern` requires 7 lines of code, but [the entire operation can be done in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70992736/256196).

Comment: @Steven Spungin tried with above pattern got no response.

Comment: To that regard, it requires more processing to replace all the non-matched text, then split on the remaining data, versus scanning the document once and having your query already in an array.

Comment: @Maana I'm cannot recall if java needs the global flag set. Also, try making the \r optional `\r?`

Comment: @Maana I see your document does not end with `;`. I will fix that.