# Regex ignoring matches between square brackets

Tags: regex, kotlin

Hi I'm trying to create a Regex to help separate a string into a series of object fields, however having issues where the individual field values themselves are lists and therefore comma separated internally.

string = "field1:1234,field2:[[1, 3],[3,4]], field3:[[1, 3],[3,4]]"

I want the regex to identify only the commas before "field2" and "field3", ignoring the ones separating the list values (e.g. 1 and 3, ] and [, 3 and 4.

I've tried using non-capturing groups to ignore the character after the commas (e.g. (,)([?!a-z]) ) but given I'm running this in Kotlin I don't think non-capturing and group separation is useful.

Is there a way to ignore string values between specified characters? E.g. ignore anything between "[[" and "]]" would work here.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How many nested levels can there be?

Comment: How exactly do you want to separate? Like what is the desired output for the string your gave in question?

Answer (score 2):

You can tweak the [existing Java recursion mimicking regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47162099/3832970) to extract all the matches you need:

```kotlin
val rx = """\w+:(?:(?=\[)(?:(?=.*?\[(?!.*?\1)(.*\](?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?\](?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)[^\[]*(?=\2$)|\w+)""".toRegex()
val matches = rx.findAll(string).map{it.value}.joinToString("\n")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TeODdF/1). *Quick details*:

- `\w+` - one or more letters, digits, underscores
- `:` - a colon
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group matching either

  - `(?=\[)(?:(?=.*?\[(?!.*?\1)(.*\](?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?\](?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)[^\[]*(?=\2$)` - a substring between two paired `[` and `]`
  - `|` - or
  - `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group.

See the [Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/p9WIYE):

```kotlin
val string = "field1:1234,field2:[[1, 3],[3,4]], field3:[[1, 3],[3,4]]"
val rx = """\w+:(?:(?=\[)(?:(?=.*?\[(?!.*?\1)(.*\](?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?\](?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)[^\[]*(?=\2$)|\w+)""".toRegex()
print( rx.findAll(string).map{it.value}.joinToString("\n") )
```

Output:

```
field1:1234
field2:[[1, 3],[3,4]]
field3:[[1, 3],[3,4]]
```