# Regex - Matching the contents between two characters only if the latter character is not followed by the latter character before the former character

Tags: java, string-matching

I'm trying to match JSON condition strings in Java and have been hitting my head against a wall trying to find a solution.
In these condition strings, conditions are JSON objects "{}", which may be evaluated on their own, or in a group. These groups are represented as arrays of condition objects "[]". I had a solution that worked fine to match the contents between characters for groups and objects respectively, however, this went out the window when I attempted to store groups inside other groups.

Example string:

```
[{"field":"type","operand":"=","value":"column"}, "&&",
  [{"field":"type","operand":"=","value":"column"}, "||", 
   {"field":"type","operand":"=","value":"column"}], "||", 
   {"field":"type","operand":"=","value":"column"}]
```

The intended outcome was to match the contents of the string between (and including) the characters [ and ].

I've worked out that what I need is to match the contents of [ ... ] until there is a ] that is not followed (somewhere ahead, i.e., .+?) by another ] before a [.
Doing a lazy search for ] will stop the match at the first occurence, but doing a greedy match will match the entire string up to the last occurence, which may contain many other groups/objects. I've experimented with lookbehinds/lookaheads, but these require statically defined character positions, and cannot stretch to find (or not find) an occurence of a character.

At this point, I'm stumped and would greatly appreciate any advice you have to offer.

Comment: Please post the regex you used to try and solve this problem.

Comment: I think you will have better results with JsonMapper and JsonNode

Comment: Using regex to process JSON is a bad match (no pun intended). Use JSON libraries to parse JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Technically possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47162098/is-it-possible-to-match-nested-brackets-with-a-regex-without-using-recursion-or/47162099#47162099) with a single regex, but probably not worth it. Note that the linked answer is for one type of parenthesis only; your program is harder because you have {} *and* [].

The problem is that nested expressions are not a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language); regex libraries can sometimes parse non-regular languages with the help of extensions (like forward and backward references), but the results are generally fragile and unreadable. This issue is [quite famous on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/252218).

Since your input is already a JSON string, you're much better off using a real JSON parser. I promise you it'll be much less painful than what you've already done.

---

If you really must use regex, I suggest doing it in iteratively:

1. Create a regex that finds all {} or [] that don't have any {} or [] inside.
2. Search for matches in your input string.
3. Replace each match with a unique token, like "TOKEN_N". Remember what was the match string for each of these tokens.
4. Repeat 2-3 until there are no more matches.

In the end you'll have transformed the input into something like

```
[TOKEN1, "&&", TOKEN2, "||", TOKEN3]
```

And a recursive dictionary of everything you replaced:

```
TOKEN1={"field":"type","operand":"=","value":"column"}
TOKEN2=[TOKEN4, "||", TOKEN5]
TOKEN3={"field":"type","operand":"=","value":"column"}
TOKEN4={"field":"type","operand":"=","value":"column"}
TOKEN5={"field":"type","operand":"=","value":"column"}
```

This is a stringified [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of your expression, and from here you can process it however you like.

Comment: Thank you very much! In the end I created a custom Json deserialiser to handle the different combination of objects in my array. I can't believe I didn't think of this earlier.